# Show LinearProgressIndicator in AppBar

Tags: flutter, dart, linearprogressindicator

I have this question how to show `LinearProgressIndicator` in my `AppBar`, when the user makes an API request like login, catch data from the server etc?

The following code is the menu:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simao/routes/app_routes.dart';
import 'package:simao/themes/themes.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

class MenuScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  // Title of appbar
  final String title;
  // Screen to show
  final Widget screen;

  const MenuScreen({Key? key, required this.title, required this.screen}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MenuScreen> createState() => _MenuScreenState();
}

class _MenuScreenState extends State<MenuScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // We need the information of menu options
    final menuOptions = AppRoutes.menuOptions;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget.title),
          // linear loading bar
          bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(1.0),
            child:
              Column(children: [

                //
                // This when is loading show the LinearProgressIndicator
                //

                if(true)...[
                  LinearProgressIndicator(
                    minHeight: 2,
                    backgroundColor: AppTheme.white,
                    // valueColor: AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(AppTheme.white),
                  ),
                ],


              ],
            ) 
          ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: widget.screen,
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        // Add a ListView to the drawer. This ensures the user can scroll
        // through the options in the drawer if there isn't enough vertical
        // space to fit everything.
        child: ListView(
          // Important: Remove any padding from the ListView.
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          children: [
            DrawerHeader(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: AppTheme.primaryColor,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: const [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 40,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage("lib/assets/logo_app/logo.png"),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 10),
                  Text(
                    "Simao",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 24,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            // Recorremos el menuOptions para crear los items
            ...menuOptions.map((item) => ListTile(
                  leading: FaIcon(item.icon),
                  title: Text(item.name),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, item.route);
                  },
                )),

            const Divider(),

            SizedBox(
              width: double.infinity,
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: AppTheme.dangerColor,
                  shadowColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                onPressed: () =>
                    Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(AppRoutes.loginRoute, (route) => false),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: const [
                    Text('Cerrar Sesión'),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ), // <-- Text
                    Icon(
                      Icons.exit_to_app,
                      size: 24.0,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The next code is to make an API request:

```dart
static Future<String> httpRequestAPI({required String rute, required Map<String, dynamic> body, int? timeOutSeconds = 10}) async {

    // SEND REQUEST TO SHOW LOADING ??

    if (!await HttpProvider().checkConnectivityState()) return json.encode(defaultResponses["noInternet"]);
    final url = Uri.https(HttpProvider.urlJFerrer, rute);
    final response = await http.post(url, headers: HttpProvider.headers, body: body)
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: timeOutSeconds!), onTimeout: () {
        return http.Response(json.encode(HttpProvider.defaultResponses['timeout']), 500);
    });

    // HIDE LOADING ??

    return response.body;
  }
```

[image: LinearProgressIndicator]

When the user makes an API request show the `LinearProgressIndicator`.

Answer (score 0):

create variable  `bool isLoading = false;`  which will contain when to show the indicator

in  `httpRequestAPI()` before the request starts, set to `true` to start showing the indicator, when the response comes, then set to `false`  I shortened the code for clarity

```
Future<String> httpRequestAPI() async {
    //Show indicator
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
  
   //simulation of waiting for a request, just a random pause within 5000 milliseconds, when it ends, then the answer has come and the indicator needs to be hidden
   await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: Random().nextInt(5000)), () {
     setState(() {
       isLoading = false;
     });
    });

    return "RESPONSE JSON STRING";
  }

 //if  isLoading == true show indicator else hide
 appBar: AppBar(
        title: isLoading ? const LinearProgressIndicator(color: Colors.deepOrange) : null,
 ),
```

complete code

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isLoading = false;


  Future<String> httpRequestAPI() async {

    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

   await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: Random().nextInt(5000)), () {
     setState(() {
       isLoading = false;
     });
    });

    return "RESPONSE JSON STRING";
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: isLoading ? const LinearProgressIndicator(color: Colors.deepOrange,) : null,
      ),
      body: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async {
       await httpRequestAPI();
      },child: const Text('API CALL'),)

    );
  }
}
```